# How do Southeastern Conference football records compare for divisional tiebreakers?

Tags: american-football, collegiate, tie-breaker

In the **SEC (Southeastern Conference)** for NCAA football, [division tiebreaker rule](https://www.secsports.com/article/11145479/sec-divisional-tie-breaker) 1.B states the following:

> B. Records of the tied teams within the division;

*In this context, precisely how do “records” compare?*

There are multiple ways I am aware of that records could be compared, and a common approach is **Win Percentage**.  In the absence of ties, the formula is `Wins / # of Games`.  This method seems to be fair when it favors a 9-0 team over a 9-1 team, or when a game is canceled under no fault of the team.  But it unfairly treats a 1-0 record the same as 10-0.

I am speculating.  Is there any concrete evidence that this method, or any other, is used for this purpose in the tiebreaker scenario?

Comment: In a normal season, each team plays the same number of games within their division. Just how the schedule is constructed.

Comment: See https://www.secsports.com/article/29616412/new-sec-opponents-set-revised-football-schedule

Comment: @joncuster That’s right, in most seasons any two-team tie only needs rule 1.A.  But canceled games can happen any season, and in 2020 it seems inevitable.

Comment: Like everything else this year, I suspect they will make it up as they go along. No doubt they are discussing options, particularly after all the cancellations this week. Just nothing public yet.